# Android Drawable setLevel(); not filling SeekBar appropriately

Tags: android, drawable, seekbar

Okay so I've been able to customize a few SeekBar's to be used as a Bar Graph type of image, but since I need to be able to switch between a Green or Red Image (depending on certain values) which you can see below. The problem is that regardless of what value I use in the setLevel for the Drawable it doesn't fill appropriately (you can see the image below for an example since the green bar should be closer to the right based on the two values)

[image]

Below is the code for the section that setups this entire MTD Commission bar section, I don't know how much of the code you would need to see so I just decided to post all of this section.

```
void setupMTDBarSection() {
    //Get Current Date and Number of Days in Current Month
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int numberOfDays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    SimpleDateFormat today = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    String currentDate = today.format(new Date());

    //Get MTD Goal value from Preferences
    String goalString = preferences.getString("keyMonthlyGoal", "0");
    float mtdGoalFloat = Float.valueOf(goalString);
    Integer mtdGoal = (int)mtdGoalFloat;
    MTDGoalValue.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(mtdGoalFloat));

    //Get Current MTD Value
    String mtdString = preferences.getString("keyMTDValue", "0");
    float mtdValueFloat = Float.valueOf(mtdString);
    Integer mtdValue = (int)mtdValueFloat;
    MTDCurrentProgress.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(mtdValueFloat));

    //Do some math to determine if the Rep is below/above the daily goal
    Integer dailyGoal = mtdGoal/numberOfDays;
    Integer currentDayGoal = dailyGoal * Integer.valueOf(currentDate);

    if (mtdValue >= currentDayGoal) {
        MTDGreenTrack.setLevel(mtdValue);
        MTDProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(MTDGreenTrack);
        MTDProgressBar.setMax(mtdGoal);
        MTDProgressBar.setProgress(mtdValue);
    }
    else {
        MTDRedTrack.setLevel(mtdValue);
        MTDProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(MTDRedTrack);
        MTDProgressBar.setMax(mtdGoal);
        MTDProgressBar.setProgress(mtdValue);
    }

    //Add Percentage to MTD Text
    NumberFormat percentFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    float percent = mtdValueFloat/mtdGoalFloat;
    String percentage = percentFormat.format(percent);
    MTDPercentText.setText("(" + percentage + ")");


    //Setup MTD Indicator
    MTDIndicator.setMax(numberOfDays);
    MTDIndicator.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(currentDate));
    MTDIndicator.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return true;
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell because we don't have your actual values, but my hunch is that you're not setting the maximum value right. If the minimum is 5000 and the max is 6000, then the "max" should be 1000. But like i said, it's hard to tell.

Comment: If you mean the values for the Progress Bar max and progress, those are the values that are displayed on the left and right. So in the pictured example, the max value is 6000 and the current progress value is 5000. I don't have a minimum value set, but I can set it to 0 if that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the issue. Apparently when you call setProgressDrawable more than once then you need to re-draw the image that is used since it looses the format that was previously there. Also, don't really need to set the level each time of the drawable as well, it matches up with the progress value of the Seekbar. Below is the code that works for me so far

```
Rect bounds = MTDProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
        MTDProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(MTDGreenTrack);
        MTDProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
        MTDProgressBar.setProgress(mtdValue);
        MTDProgressBar.setMax(mtdGoal);
```