# SeekBar not displaying correctly on Android 2.x

Tags: android

I have `SeekBar`s in an application which operate as expected and return values that I expect. However, on Android 2.x they display oddly.

[image]

I've looked for other similar things such as [Android Drawable setLevel(); not filling SeekBar appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279971/android-drawable-setlevel-not-filling-seekbar-appropriately), but that is for a custom drawable. Otherwise I'm having trouble coming up with search terms for this issue to get anywhere.

In this case, all I'm doing is

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_seek);
seekBar.setProgress(5);
seekBar.setMax(20);
```

If I move the slider, it properly fills the `SeekBar` the moment it's moved.

Any idea on what is going on?

Comment: Perhaps call invalidate() on the seekbar once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting this, I realized the problem was the order of the method calls.

**Incorrect**

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_seek);
seekBar.setProgress(5);
seekBar.setMax(20);
```

**Correct**

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_seek);
seekBar.setMax(20);
seekBar.setProgress(5);
```

From what I gather if you first call *setProgress(5)* in my case, the system will set the drawable to display the progress as 5% since it is 5 / 100 and 100 is the default maximum.

Then if you call *setMax(20)*, the value of 5 is still valid but the drawable is no longer valid and is not recalculated to display as 25% (5 / 20) of the bar.

Doing *setMax(20)* first will compel the drawable to be calculated correctly once you use *setProgress(5)*.

In case it's of use to anyone, I tested this on Android 2.1, 2.2, 4.1 and 4.2.

- Android 2.1 and 2.2 have this bug, the order matters
- Android 4.1 and 4.2 do not have this bug, the order doesn't matter

Essentially to remain backwards compatible, always do *setMax(int)* first and then *setProgress(int)*.

Comment: I just ran into the very same thing on Android 4.1.2. This isn't just some freak circumstance you appear to be experiencing, it's the rule.